# Directory structure for Node.js and Angularjs prokect

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I am starting a node.js application using angular.js

I need to setup the directory structure but am a bit unclear on how it should be?

Any ideas would be good.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular seed project is very basic. It'll work pretty well; however, other options include yeoman and ng-boilerplate.

Install yeoman and the angular js

```
npm install -g yo   // this will install yeoman, bower, and grunt
npm install -g generator-angular
```

Creating an app with folder structure is simple:

```
yo angular
```

However, there's also the ng-boilerplate route: https://github.com/ngbp/ng-boilerplate.

Ng-boilerplate organizes your project by features (less, js and template that are part of a single feature all go into one directory). I actually like the ng-boilerplate much better than yeoman because of this issue.

Both use bower and grunt... Bower is a dependency management solution for all the packages like jquery, bootstrap, etc. This means you don't have to worry about keeping track of the version of files or storing them, bower will go out and get it for you. Grunt is a simple way to run tests, build and preview your website. I'd recommend check both of these out.

Comment: Also in regards to the routing do I use express for routing or angular?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "express for routing or angular".

Comment: Sorry I meant configuring routes for url's.

Comment: I think you should try them... it'll make sense when you see the documentation and sample project.

Comment: Have you used Expressjs or any other middleware with ng-boilerplate to do the server side stuff?

Answer (score 0):

It depends quite a bit on what you are building and how complicated it will get. The angular team provides the [angular seed project](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) as a basic configuration, but most people recommend dividing things up by "page" or by "module" rather then file type.

I would suggest starting with angular-seed, and if it becomes unwieldy, start splitting stuff up. I usually do one file per "entity" (service, directive, etc), root folders based on module (main groups of functionality in the page), and sub folders when I feel I need more organization.

Answer (score 0):

Angular has a whole [tutorial section](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial). That tutorial matches an example project available on Github: https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat

There is a basic but very rational directory/folder structure right there.

Seems to be similar in the [seed project](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed).